# how to stop content of sidebar div jumping to bottom of display on detection of height change

Tags: google-chrome, height, html

I'm a novice on HTML, so please forgive any obvious mistakes. I'm trying to write a web page that has a titlebar and sidebar and an area for content. Generally, I want the user to be able to scroll through the content while the titlebar and sidebar (which contains link buttons) remain fixed. On some devices, the display resolution may be such that the entire sidebar is not visible, so below a certain display height, the page changes the behaviour of the sidebar such that it becomes scrollable (not fixed in position).

I've nearly got it working, but on reducing the height of the browser window to simulate the small displays, the sidebar jumps to the bottom of the display. I need it to remain at the top of the page.

An additional problem is in zooming in on the page using Chrome on Android (on a standard desktop browser there is no issue). The content warps in ways I find difficult to put into words. If you can guess at a solution to this too, it would be of great assistance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>title</title>
<style>
body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #5c5c5c;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: FuturaLT;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: justify;
}
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
h2{
    margin: 0;
}
a:link{
    color: #CB4C2F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
    color: #CB4C2F;
}
a:active, a:hover{
    color: #b60a00;
}
.button_1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;          
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: normal;
    font-family: FuturaLT;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;        
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #c0c0c0;        
}
.button_1:hover{
    color: #c0c0c0;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.button_1:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    color: #000000;
}
#header_1{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    color: #dddddd;
    background: #5c5c5c;
}
#main_1{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dddddd;
}
#sidebar_1{
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    width: 130px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 55px;
    background: #5c5c5c;
    text-align: center;
}
@media(max-height: 790px){
    #sidebar_1 {
        position: relative;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header_1">
<h1>TITLE</h1>
</div>
<div id="main_1">
This is some text.
<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec porta pellentesque accumsan. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla ultrices ipsum imperdiet nulla gravida tempor. Vivamus sit amet nisi feugiat, laoreet urna id, blandit est. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur eget porta tortor. Suspendisse non tempor velit, id ultrices erat. Nullam fermentum placerat tellus quis sollicitudin. Vivamus viverra consequat lorem id condimentum.

Suspendisse potenti. Fusce laoreet dolor ut quam eleifend laoreet. Pellentesque in ligula hendrerit, vehicula dui id, pellentesque risus. Vestibulum condimentum nisl ut placerat euismod. Morbi in neque lacus. Nam pharetra tortor a felis porta accumsan. Nulla euismod dignissim ligula vel fringilla. Vestibulum eget semper dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.

Fusce erat nunc, fermentum eget orci ut, elementum aliquet ipsum. Cras vitae imperdiet orci. Fusce ac sapien egestas, feugiat justo eget, aliquet quam. In sit amet sapien placerat, porta libero et, tempus nibh. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis nec erat sit amet quam mattis mattis. Morbi lacus quam, lobortis sed augue a, egestas cursus velit. Aliquam convallis eleifend nunc, sit amet volutpat mauris. Fusce maximus porttitor nisl, quis luctus nisl pellentesque nec.

Etiam viverra hendrerit nulla tempor efficitur. Aliquam ligula libero, volutpat sit amet tempor non, finibus eget orci. Sed euismod sit amet nisi eget convallis. Proin vestibulum posuere neque placerat condimentum. Sed commodo ut eros gravida posuere. Maecenas feugiat vitae risus porta rhoncus. Etiam semper dolor eu sem dignissim pulvinar. Donec ut nisl sed dui varius pharetra. Curabitur a hendrerit libero. In tristique eleifend enim, et euismod augue pretium sed. Nunc quam tellus, posuere id mattis sit amet, lobortis eget orci. Sed placerat iaculis neque eu facilisis. Integer a tellus vel nisi pulvinar ullamcorper sed ut elit. Donec commodo sed enim eu tempor.

Maecenas nulla tortor, bibendum ut lectus ut, porta maximus dolor. Integer lorem orci, ultrices eu ultricies sed, fermentum sed enim. Praesent efficitur semper mauris. Sed viverra feugiat dui ut eleifend. Morbi vitae semper felis, eu dignissim est. Praesent eget eleifend est. Praesent molestie dui tortor. Fusce luctus dignissim elit vitae tempor. Duis tempus pharetra metus quis suscipit. In venenatis maximus pulvinar. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur at turpis non justo ultrices accumsan. Maecenas tempor laoreet erat, vel hendrerit dui placerat eget.

Vestibulum dignissim felis vestibulum, commodo quam et, aliquet justo. Curabitur maximus turpis lacus, id faucibus libero euismod non. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Pellentesque vel nisl quis dolor rutrum interdum. Vivamus vitae ultricies nisi, lacinia dictum turpis. Cras consequat dictum elit. In sollicitudin rutrum pretium. Curabitur leo lorem, imperdiet at pretium et, commodo sed mauris.

Maecenas consectetur sem eu leo elementum, eu elementum velit varius. Quisque vel egestas sem. Morbi sodales fringilla eleifend. Morbi pretium porta porta. Nullam id nisi ligula. Donec ullamcorper tellus id semper commodo. Morbi quis nulla libero.

Curabitur ornare urna urna. Aliquam condimentum consectetur odio, ac convallis arcu accumsan eu. Ut consequat diam a lectus pellentesque, id tempus nunc placerat. Suspendisse sit amet mi leo. Sed eu elit finibus, pharetra nisi vel, mollis dui. Donec mollis placerat libero, vel lacinia est. Vestibulum vitae ullamcorper nibh.

Duis nisl velit, tincidunt sed cursus eu, faucibus vitae neque. Donec tortor sem, rutrum quis metus laoreet, egestas maximus erat. Ut feugiat erat lacus, sed vulputate libero facilisis non. Curabitur eget ante at neque facilisis ultrices eget vel sem. Sed bibendum velit molestie, pharetra ipsum quis, laoreet risus. Proin porta pulvinar ultricies. In hendrerit, metus vel ornare maximus, justo mi porttitor ipsum, at tempor nunc tellus a urna. Nulla ut fermentum leo. Nulla facilisi. Praesent interdum at dui a volutpat. Sed vel odio dapibus, tincidunt dui non, tincidunt nulla. Proin convallis, massa vitae placerat condimentum, massa nisl tincidunt eros, sit amet dignissim mi turpis sit amet tortor. Sed pharetra nulla in purus sodales ullamcorper.

Vestibulum at pellentesque enim. In sit amet vulputate mauris. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam euismod quam et sem luctus, a vehicula metus volutpat. Nam commodo efficitur rutrum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla sit amet justo ipsum. Donec pulvinar dui in libero interdum, id imperdiet ante suscipit. Duis at arcu odio. Nam ut hendrerit dolor. Nunc rhoncus ac orci nec maximus. Donec bibendum lorem a augue sodales rutrum. Donec quis molestie metus, in fermentum ex. Sed bibendum elit neque, id malesuada mauris pharetra at. Nulla facilisis purus in turpis efficitur, eu consectetur elit dictum.

Nunc tristique, turpis eget convallis pulvinar, lacus urna gravida lorem, nec lobortis orci urna ac ex. Etiam consequat aliquam lectus nec laoreet. Aliquam vitae felis lorem. Proin cursus nunc ut consequat laoreet. Pellentesque laoreet quis nulla vitae iaculis. Ut pretium lectus quis lectus fermentum viverra. Fusce interdum, turpis in sollicitudin vehicula, urna augue scelerisque ex, vel porttitor nunc sem quis justo. Nulla mollis faucibus aliquet. Proin feugiat ut metus nec semper. Nulla ac elit ac tellus dictum varius accumsan in sapien. Integer consectetur maximus augue, id tincidunt turpis commodo vitae. Donec convallis massa risus, a sollicitudin nisl tincidunt semper. Praesent sem mauris, cursus eget ligula id, aliquet pellentesque metus.

Vestibulum et interdum nisi, non rhoncus augue. Morbi ultrices egestas neque in luctus. Sed consequat ultricies odio ut consectetur. Mauris elit odio, faucibus in felis at, dapibus sagittis nisl. Aenean ut accumsan nibh. Proin sed elit eget urna tincidunt faucibus. Mauris vel rutrum libero, ac maximus orci.

Sed consectetur neque fermentum purus rhoncus vehicula. Proin viverra neque nulla, faucibus rhoncus metus volutpat vitae. Maecenas mollis odio in felis vulputate, ultricies condimentum turpis aliquam. Ut tincidunt, lorem a consequat laoreet, velit dolor semper leo, eget interdum lectus erat sit amet urna. Curabitur a ullamcorper ex. Cras nec enim dictum, semper felis a, fermentum urna. Aliquam et finibus felis. Integer ut suscipit ligula, ac lacinia turpis. Etiam sed turpis et diam cursus tincidunt non volutpat lorem. Quisque erat sem, suscipit venenatis mauris eget, lacinia ultrices nisl. Nunc at massa condimentum, facilisis erat sed, pellentesque nunc. Nulla augue dui, bibendum ac aliquet eget, dapibus eget nisi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In vitae consectetur eros.

Donec porta magna at nisi feugiat porta. Etiam nisi turpis, feugiat pulvinar facilisis ut, convallis ac ex. Nullam mattis quam sit amet porta iaculis. Curabitur sit amet ante venenatis, posuere leo vitae, gravida neque. Aliquam et nibh cursus, interdum nisi vitae, malesuada sapien. Mauris laoreet pharetra nibh ut laoreet. Suspendisse potenti. Etiam aliquet congue pretium.

Duis ullamcorper ultrices elit et pharetra. Curabitur nec rhoncus elit. Duis vel magna ut velit venenatis pharetra ac vel neque. Vivamus non iaculis eros. Ut ut aliquam nisl. Curabitur tempor eget massa vitae condimentum. Fusce commodo nulla nec leo facilisis, a sollicitudin diam venenatis. Nullam finibus orci nec pharetra aliquet.

Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse convallis cursus augue, non hendrerit arcu. Duis et sem ultricies, varius neque quis, facilisis mauris. Morbi ornare vitae felis in interdum. Etiam hendrerit, magna id egestas gravida, purus sapien mattis lacus, sed ornare felis neque a quam. Fusce vel malesuada mauris. Etiam a orci diam. Nullam accumsan euismod erat. Phasellus vehicula efficitur vehicula. Phasellus lacinia pharetra dictum. Vivamus eleifend elit odio, non egestas urna pellentesque ut. Nunc metus neque, placerat id varius eget, lacinia sit amet tellus. Nunc interdum ullamcorper dolor, non convallis mi finibus vitae. Quisque sed eleifend neque.

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis volutpat urna et euismod commodo. Cras faucibus ex mauris, eget euismod nunc blandit sed. Nulla facilisi. Duis congue ligula est, sed dapibus lorem convallis sed. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Curabitur pharetra quis turpis sit amet suscipit. Integer commodo sollicitudin imperdiet. Morbi consectetur pretium placerat. Integer libero nisi, euismod quis ullamcorper vel, volutpat eu enim. Pellentesque augue justo, volutpat id venenatis eu, dapibus sed nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
</div>
<div id="sidebar_1">
    <input value="HOME" onclick="location.href='index.html';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
    <input value="CERN" onclick="location.href='http://home.web.cern.ch/';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
    <input value="ATLAS" onclick="location.href='http://atlas.ch/';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
    <input value="CMS" onclick="location.href='http://cms.web.cern.ch/';" type="button" class="button_1"><br><br>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```